# By default Order is not working in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

We have using Datatable with serverside data fetching by ajax.

But, `"order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]` is not working

This is my data table code

```js
columns = [
  { "data": "fee" },
  { "data": "net_total" }
];

$('#fundViewLatest').dataTable({
  oLanguage: {
  sLengthMenu: "<select class='btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true'>" +
    "<option value='10' class='dropdown-item'>10</option>" +
    "<option value='ALL' class='dropdown-item'>ALL</option>" +
    "</select>"
  },
  "pageLength": 20,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "processing": true,
  "deferRender": true,
  "bLengthChange": false, // can change the length
  "order": [ [ 0, "desc" ] ],
  "ajax": {
    "url": MailUrl + 'pages/fundviewlatest',
    "type": "GET"
  },
  "columns": columns,
  "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {}
});
```

Comment: Could you please add the "fundViewLatest" HTML?

Comment: It does work, see this example - http://live.datatables.net/wakakifu/1/edit . The problem will be with your server-side script. In that example, this is sent to the server: "order[0][column]:2
order[0][dir]:desc", so it's upto that server-side script to return the necessary rows.

Comment: Thanks,  colin0117